# Switch Case Error Validation

Tags: java, validation, error-handling, switch-statement

Just starting Java so it's probably a simple question but couldn't find any questions like mine so figured I would post one.

I am writing a "main menu" with options 1-8. I figured out how to error handle when someone types a number larger than 8 and less than 1 but I can't figure out how to give them an error message if they type a character or letter...

```
    while(menuChoice != 8)
        {
        //main menu that loops

        switch(menuChoice)
        {
        case 1: 
            //code
            break;

        case 2:
            //code
            break;

        case 3:
            //code
            break;

        case 4:
                            //code
            break;

        case 5:
            //code
            break;

        case 6:
                            //code
            break;

        case 7:
                            //code
            break;

        case 8:
                            //code
            break; 

        default: 
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid Menu Selection."); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your conditional is not doing what you think it is, also. Perhaps check the input before deciding what to do with only-valid input?

Comment: What type is `menuChoice` and how do you retrieve it?

Comment: menuChoice is my scanner name.. I should've labeled that!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this compiles, what you're asking would be impossible.  You're switching on a number, so you can't check if the number is a character.  Your code wouldn't compile if that were possible.

You should take the user input as a `String` and validate the String.  If the String has non-numeric values in it, then throw an error.  If it doesn't, convert it to a number then execute your switch.

A better design would be to have a validation layer.  Once the input is validated, just assume it's valid thereafter.

Pseudocode:

```
String input = //
if (containsNonNumerics(input))
    throw error
inputAsInt = castToInt(input)
if (outOfRange(inputAsInt)
    throw error
switch //your current code goes here
```

Comment: I did not know switch could only handle numeric values... That makes sense, because I have tried everything (I know so far) to get it to work! I will try your suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: @user2832187 I'm not saying it can only handle numeric values.  I'm saying if you say `x != 2` and that code compiles, that mean `x` has to be some numeric type so it can not have a value of characters.  I've inferred some details from the code you gave.

Answer (score 0):

First off, having that while loop is not going to give you the functionality that you want. You should look into how to use [KeyAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html) in order to be able to receive input events from the keyboad, e.g. a number being pressed, and then you can validate that it is actually a number, and if it is you can then use your switch statement to determine the proper code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that menuChoice is a character. In which case, you can either do a manual check that

```
if('0' <= mc && mc <= '9') {
  // do your regular checks
}
```

If it is a string then do a

```
try {
  Integer.parseInt(mc)
} catch (NumberFormatException e) { // Not a number. Do your error reporting stuff }
```

HTH.

Comment: Sorry! menuChoice is my scanner name.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Switch statment work only with numeric types (int, byte, char, short). If you try add in switch anything else the compailer wouldent allowe you in general. But if you somehow (cating or other way) want to add in switch statment varible you must befor check it with if statment if the varible is type that you want.
Example:

```
if(var instanceof String){
    System.out.println("Error we don't acceped type string");
}
else{
    switch(var){
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I did not know that yet! I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

Use this function before entering into while loop and display the error message.

```
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
  NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
  ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
  formatter.parse(str, pos);
  return str.length() == pos.getIndex();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int menuChoice ;

//Now get input from customer in menuChoice 
//Your logic goes herr... example menuChoice = ..whateverinput

//After the input is  captured then validate
if(menuChoice <1 || menuChoice >8 )
     {
        //main menu that loops
        switch(menuChoice)
        {
        case 1: 
            //code
            break;

        case 2:
            //code
            break;

        case 3:
            //code
            break;

        case 4:
                            //code
            break;

        case 5:
            //code
            break;

        case 6:
                            //code
            break;

        case 7:
                            //code
            break;

        case 8:
                            //code
            break; 

        default: 
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid Menu Selection."); 
         }
        
else {

 System.out.println("Please Enter Valid Entry");
}
```

Comment: The question was how to give an error message for non-numerical input. This answer only gives an error message for certain input numbers and says where to put the code that would be required to handle non-numeric input.